# How to rewrite URLs that cause duplicate content?

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I have a lot of links with a double URL structure. Basically, I need a `.htaccess` rule that redirects all URLs that start `/de` (for German language) to the same URL with only a `/`.

```
example.com/de/Shop/Tradition/Jagd-Forst/
```

to

```
example.com/Shop/Tradition/Jagd-Forst/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite rule should match starting with `/de/` (with an optional strating slash, capture everything afterwards with `(.*)` and redirect to the capture group (`$1`) with a 301 permanent redirect:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?de/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^de/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

I got another tip, but don't know which one is "better"? :-)

Comment: I added the "starts with" from that to my answer.  The other difference is the optional starting slash (`/?') in my rule which allows it to be used either in .htaccess or in httpd.conf.  Without a beginning slash, the rule can ONLY be used in .htaccess, with a a beginning slash, the rule can ONLY be used in httpd.conf. With the question mark making the slash optional, the rule can be used in either place.